# reading appconfig file for serilog

Tags: c#, serilog

I have `Logger.cs` class where I am initializing serilog settings as follows:

```
_logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.File(_filepath, restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Debug, shared: true, rollOnFileSizeLimit: true)
                .CreateLogger();
```

I want to read the size of the file from app.config file. 
I have the app.config file as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="serilog:using:File" value="Serilog.Sinks.File" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:File.fileSizeLimitBytes" value="2000" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

But looks like `appsettings` is not read at all. because I can see more than 2kb file getting generated.
What I have missed here?

How my logger class will read from `app.config` file, have I missed any settings in assemblyinfo class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Serilog configuration via `App.config` does not "merge" with the configuration that you have defined via C# code... These are additive. Meaning that, in your example, you are configuring two independent sinks, that are both writing to a file.

However, because you did not specify the file path for the sink in the App.config, it's ignoring that sink and not configuring it, and only the second sink is being configured (in the C# code).

If you want to use the App.config configuration, then your XML should include a file path, in addition to the `fileSizeLimitBytes`:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Debug"/>
    <add key="serilog:using:File" value="Serilog.Sinks.File" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:File.path" value="log.txt" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:File.rollOnFileSizeLimit" value="true" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:File.fileSizeLimitBytes" value="2000" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And your C# code would just read the settings from the App.config, without the "extra" sink.

```
_logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
    .CreateLogger();
```

ps: Notice that I also configured the `MinimumLevel` via App.config. That's not a requirement, but usually makes sense if are already configuring Serilog sinks via App.config.

Comment: as you mentioned i have removed writeto.file from C# code and added above to app config. Still not working

Comment: is there any other way to have xml file from where the filesize can be read by LoggerConfiguration()?

Comment: @RemSan Did you enable `rollOnFileSizeLimit` in the config?

Comment: @RemSan If you want to have different parameters of the _same_ sink instance configuration split between C# code and App.config, then you cannot use `Serilog.Settings.AppSettings`. You'll have to create your own `appSettings` values, read them via `ConfigurationManager` and set it in your code.

Comment: HI @C.AugustoProiete - i use only the AppSettings config and enabled them on the code as per above (and by their wiki) but to no luck. Its not reading them at all. Do i need to use using:sink in the appsettings config?

Comment: @Ak777 Hard to say without seeing any of your code and/or config. I suggest you ask a new question here on SO with the details of your scenario

Comment: Thanks - My issue was that I had everything I needed except this particular item: `<add key="serilog:using:File" value="Serilog.Sinks.File" />`

Answer (score 2):

> You can mix and match XML and code-based configuration, but each sink
>   must be configured either using XML or in code-sinks added in code
>   can't be modified via app settings.

So if you need to use `App.config` file you will need to move all configuration to it as below

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Debug"/>
  <add key="serilog:using:File" value="Serilog.Sinks.File" />
  <add key="serilog:write-to:File.path" value="logs\log.txt" />
  <add key="serilog:write-to:File.shared" value="true" />
  <add key="serilog:write-to:File.rollOnFileSizeLimit" value="true" />
  <add key="serilog:write-to:File.fileSizeLimitBytes" value="2000" />
</appSettings>
```

And creating logger instance using below code

```
_logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Just to add the same comment here as the previous one, @ElasticCode, by doing the above, the code doesnt recognize the configurations and doesnt add logs to eithr the File or Console (i am configuring the File and Console as sinks). I even used the "using" and without using it too. But it didnt take any effect at all, that i could see the logs being added to the respective sinks.

Comment: @Ak777 Please share your appSettings configuration

Comment: `<add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Debug"/>
<add key="serilog:using:Console" value="Serilog.Sinks.Console" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Console"/>
<add key="serilog:using:File" value="Serilog.Sinks.File" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:File"/>
<add key="serilog:write-to:File.pathFormat" value="C:\Logs\App-Log-{Date}.log" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:File.rollingInterval" value="Day"/>
<add key="serilog:write-to:File.outputTemplate" value="[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"/>`

Comment: \\ Registering logger in DI
`Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
            .CreateLogger();
container.Register(() => Log.Logger, Lifestyle.Singleton);`

Comment: @Ak777 `pathFormat` parameter used with RollingFile sink, You need to use `path` parameter 
`<add key="serilog:write-to:File.path" value="C:\Logs\App-Log-.log" />`